# Firebase where filter not working on date field

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My situation: I'm filtering on a date field, and I require it to be `null`. However, a database record in which the date field is not null is somehow making it through. I'm using the Firebase Emulator.

What I've tried:

- remove all filters except this one, didn't work.
- Change other filters (i.e. not on date fields) to make sure that the stream as a whole is working: check.

This is the code block that's supposed to filter that `finishedTDate == null`:

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('events')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
      .where('event', isEqualTo: 'createAndSaveItems')
      // problem statement:
      .where('finishedTDate', isEqualTo: null)
      // problem statement ^
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {
    var filteredEventData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
      data['id'] = doc.id;
      return data;
    }).toList();
    streamController5.add(filteredEventData);
  });
```

This is the function it's in:

```
    Stream<
    Tuple5<List<Item>, List<Item>, List<Item>, List<Map<String, dynamic>>,
        List<Map<String, dynamic>>>>? getStreams(String userId) {
  Timestamp currentTime = Timestamp.now();
  Timestamp oneHourFromNow = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
      currentTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch + 3600000);
  Timestamp oneHourAgo = Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
      currentTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch - 3600000);

  StreamController<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> streamController1 =
      StreamController();
  StreamController<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> streamController2 =
      StreamController();
  StreamController<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> streamController3 =
      StreamController();
  StreamController<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamController4 =
      StreamController();
  StreamController<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamController5 =
      StreamController();

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('items')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {
    var filteredDocs = snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
      return (doc['dDate'] as Timestamp).millisecondsSinceEpoch == 0 &&
          (doc['sDate'] as Timestamp).millisecondsSinceEpoch == 0;
    }).toList();
    streamController1.add(filteredDocs);
  });

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('items')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {
    var filteredDocs = snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
      return (doc['due'] as Timestamp).millisecondsSinceEpoch <=
              oneHourFromNow.millisecondsSinceEpoch &&
          (doc['dDate'] as Timestamp).millisecondsSinceEpoch != 0;
    }).toList();
    streamController2.add(filteredDocs);
  });

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('items')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
      .orderBy('dDate')
      .limit(1)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {
    var filteredDocs = snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
      return (doc['due'] as Timestamp).millisecondsSinceEpoch >
          oneHourFromNow.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    }).toList();
    streamController3.add(filteredDocs);
  });

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('files')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
      .where('include', isEqualTo: true)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {
    var filteredDocsData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
      data['id'] = doc.id;
      return data;
    }).toList();
    streamController4.add(filteredDocsData);
  });

  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('events')
      .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
      .where('event', isEqualTo: 'createAndSaveItems')
      .where('finishedTDate', isEqualTo: null)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {
    var filteredEventData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data();
      data['id'] = doc.id;
      return data;
    }).toList();
    streamController5.add(filteredEventData);
  });

  return Rx.combineLatest5(
    transformListToItem(streamController1.stream).startWith([]),
    transformListToItem(streamController2.stream).startWith([]),
    transformListToItem(streamController3.stream).startWith([]),
    streamController4.stream.startWith([]),
    streamController5.stream.startWith([]),
    (List<Item> items1,
            List<Item> items2,
            List<Item> items3,
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> files,
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> eventData) =>
        Tuple5(items1, items2, items3, files, eventData),
  );
}
```

This is what's being returned in my debugger:

[image]

Sorry I underlined the wrong variable, `finishedTDate` is supposed to be underlined.

Why is the filter not working? Filters that are not on date fields work, which is why I know this isn't me accidentally looking at the wrong variable.

Database structure:

[image]

Comment: So you say that you have documents inside your database, where the `finishedTDate` fields hold the value of `null`, and those documents aren't returned by your query? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: At this moment, I have no documents that match `finishedTDate == null`, so I'm expecting no results. Yes certainly, I have added the database structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I was able to reproduce this in Flutter, and it is different behavior from the underlying native (web) SDK.

- [Flutter repro](https://zapp.run/edit/firestore-query-null-date-zr1q06yyr1r0) (in Dartpad)
- [JavaScript non-repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-query-null-date) (in StackBlitz)

The problem doesn't just happen on date fields for me, but on any field when you try to retrieve null values. I've only tested on web, but that's enough to flag this as a bug.

I reported issue [#11874](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11874) on the FlutterFire repo for this, so I recommend following there for updates.

---

**Update**

One of the devs followed up on the issue I created, and it turns out that you have to use the `isNull` condition in Flutter. So:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('events')
    .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
    .where('event', isEqualTo: 'createAndSaveItems')
    .where('finishedTDate', isNull: true) //
```

I tested it in my Dartpad testbed, and it works.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and bug report, Frank! I'll be sure to follow that thread.